# CSS linking not working

Tags: html, css

one of my students has the following code:

```
    <title> Portfolio
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="portfolio1style.css">
</head>
```

portfolio1style.css is in the same file as HTML file and is definitely spelled correctly.
the CSS works when we put it in the doc internally. 
What's going on here?
Thanks

Comment: href instead of src

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 2):

You want it to look like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio1style.css">`

**Switch the `src` to `href`**

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `href="portfolio1style.css"` instead of src